# Set ASP.NET Textbox value, wrapped in hidden div from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

I have ASP.NET textbox 'txtSelectAssessmentID' which is wrap in hidden div. I need to change its value when user select new from grid. All is working fine except if ASP.NET textbox is not in hidden div

```
<div class="HiddenField">
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtSelectAssessmentID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        //..... other textboxes
  </div>
```

### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#AssessmentWithRemediationGrid').on('cellclick', function (event) {

 var datarow = $('#AssessmentWithRemediationGrid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', event.args.rowindex);

    var selectedEnrolmentID = datarow.AssessmentID;

    alert($("#<%=txtSelectAssessmentID.ClientID%>").attr("id"));

    $("#<%=txtSelectAssessmentID.ClientID%>").val(selectedEnrolmentID);
    //....remain code
 });
```

Comment: What is happening now?? what you are getting in `alert`?

Comment: I am getting server generated asp:textbox id by ... $("#<%=txtSelectAssessmentID.ClientID%>").attr("id") ... even in hidden block

Comment: can you please brief your question more.. Its quite unclear..

Comment: I want to set ASP.text value from jQuery or javascript

Comment: If you are getting proper id in `alert`, then this line -  `$("#<%=txtSelectAssessmentID.ClientID%>").val(selectedEnrolmentID);` should work. Isn't it working?

Comment: no its not for some reason

Comment: Just run `$("#<%=txtSelectAssessmentID.ClientID%>").val(selectedEnrolmentID);` in browser console and see whether value is setting?

Comment: Are you getting value in `selectedEnrolmentID ` ?